# Ground truth from the jackal robot

Tags: ros, jackal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a simulation environment using the jackal in gazebo without using the laser scanner.
I have a small program that publishes the velocity commands and subscribes to the odometry topic to get odometer readings.
I have to get the exact position of the robot in order to calculate the shift in the odometry readings.
Is there a topic I can subscribe to, to get the position at any time of the robot?
Would it be the base_link frame which should be considered for this?

In the absence of the laser scanner, how does the jackal calculate its ground truth?

Thanks and regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258748/ground-truth-from-the-jackal-robot/) by [rsmitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/28985/rsmitha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the p3d plugin, it publishes the ground truth pose of the robot via a odometry message. Example use in [this Q/A](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5308/getting-the-gazebo-plugin-p3d-working-hydro/).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2